# margin-bottom on HTML element causes extra space above it - Firebug doesn't reveal why

Tags: html, css, margins

I'm building this page: http://gwwc2.centreforeffectivealtruism.org/. As you'll see, the top 2 visible HTML elements are an image (the text 'Giving What We Can' against a blue background) and a horizontal menu. I want there to be no space between these, but there is, for no reason I can see in the CSS, or in Firebug or Chrome's equivalent Developer Tools. (Here's a [video of me trying to find the reason in Chrome](http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/clh62a57n) - I click on one element after the other, and would normally see some margin or padding which explained the gap between the 2 elements highlighted, but as you can see don't.)

Since posting this mattmanser pointed out that removing the margin-bottom of the bottom HTML element (the menu) fixes the problem. My question is now why a bottom margin should cause space above this? (A secondary question is whether are there any better tools than Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools for spotting these things, as they didn't reveal this.)

### HTML/CSS (skippable)

You're probably best off examining the HTML and CSS yourself (it's slightly complex, because it's within a Zen-based Drupal theme), but here's a partial sample. The 2 elements are:

```
<div id="gwwc-logo-header">
    <a href="/">
        <img src="/sites/givingwhatwecan.org/themes/gwwc2/images/chrome/header/top-blue-header.png" alt="Giving What We Can">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="region region-header">
  <div id="block-superfish-1" class="block block-superfish first last odd">
</div>
```

None of these IDs/classes have any margin/padding set that I can see (except that as noted `.block` has a *bottom* margin).

*Question edited to reflect margin-bottom being responsible*

Answer (score 3):

Element id `block-superfish-1` has the class `block` which adds a `margin-bottom` of `1.5em` to the element.

That is causing the gap. You click on the element at the end of the video and the value is showing up in the explorer.

Comment: +1 You're quite right, that fixes the problem! I did actually mention that in my question, but it's a *bottom* margin so I don't understand why it causes extra space *above* it. I'll edit my question accordingly in case you want to edit yours/comment to answer this...

Comment: I believe I am having this exact issue (I'm so glad I found your question since I've been pulling my hair out for hours)! Why would a bottom margin affect the top?!?

Comment: @snap, @tog22 That menu is really floating, which means it appears under the effectively empty parent divs. Floating elements don't contribute to the height, hence the parent divs have 0 height. Thus when you add a margin to the empty div, as the menu is really hovering underneath it forces down the menu. It's very hard to spot as the `ul` pretends it's not floating by listing a height in inspectors. You can 'fix' this by adding a <div class="clear"></div> after the `ul`, or see it suddenly fix itself by removing the float property from the `li`s.  It's stupid, but that's CSS for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around for your problem. Add the below code to your CSS.

```
#gwwc-logo-header {
height: 45px;
}
```

Cheers !!!